# Excel indirect columns from another sheet for row dragdown

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to dragdown a formula which is

```
=IF(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$257:E$261)>0,"3",IF(AND(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$232:E$256)>0,SUM(SecurityLevels!E$2:E$231)>0),"2",IF(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$2:E$231)>0,"1","0")))
```

Currently it won't drag down column number to be F, G, H, etc. My current sheet I am doing this in is ReportOwnerQuery. The sheet I'm trying to dragdown from is SecurityLevels. Manually changing the Column letter works but is super inefficient as I have to do it to JF. The Security levels sheet has a list of names in Row 1 starting in Column C and going to JF. Could I make an Indirect that will help with this so I can just drag it down to change column letter? Will be a lot quicker than doing Find and Replace every line.

I have tried:

Find and Replace every line, it works but is super inefficient.
Tried a Indirect() but I can't get it working quite properly. I got it working in the SecurityLevels sheet for part of the complex calculation I was doing. Here is one cells example: "=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'ReportOwnerQuery'!AD"&COLUMN()-1),"*"&$A260&"*")"

```
=IF(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$257:E$261)>0,"3",IF(AND(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$232:E$256)>0,SUM(SecurityLevels!E$2:E$231)>0),"2",IF(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$2:E$231)>0,"1","0")))
```

Being able to drag this down the Column with the column changing from E to F to G etc for each line ```=IF(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$257:E$261)>0,"3",IF(AND(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$232:E$256)>0,SUM(SecurityLevels!E$2:E$231)>0),"2",IF(SUM(SecurityLevels!E$2:E$231)>0,"1","0")))

Comment: A solution from copy pasting would be what I am using until I figure out a formulated way was to switch to copy the formula to a  an empty row, drag it to the right as much as I needed the go into Formula view mode (CTRL+`). Copy and paste the formulas with columns different into Notepad then paste where I wanted to originally drag down.

Comment: So if I understand your problem currently, you are dragging down but you want the columns to change instead of the rows? So dragging one row down should change E to F?

Comment: @Jerry Yes that is what I am trying to do with Indirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve it using `INDEX`. That said, incorporating this in your formula would give:

```
=IF(SUM(INDEX(SecurityLevels!E$257:JF$261,0,ROW()))>0,"3",IF(AND(SUM(INDEX(SecurityLevels!E$232:JF$256,0,ROW()))>0,SUM(INDEX(SecurityLevels!E$2:JF$231,0,ROW()))>0),"2",IF(SUM(INDEX(SecurityLevels!E$2:JF$231,0,ROW()))>0,"1","0")))
```

Just testing a bit dragging the formula down:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the solution. This works conditionally as part of making this giant spreadsheet all automated. Thank you very much!